# Unable to use WriteTo.ElasticSearch using serilog sink for elasticsearch

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, console-application, serilog

I am using SeriLog 2.5.0 and the Serilogs.Sinks.ElasticSearch 5.3.0 nuget packages to ingest the logs to ElasticSearch (It is a console application).

I am working on a POC code to check if i am able to write my logs to local ElasticSearch Instance. I am following the below tutorial

https://improveandrepeat.com/2014/10/elasticsearch-as-a-sink-for-serilog/

I am not able to use the below code as ElasticSearch is not found in the WriteTo

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration().WriteTo.ElasticSearch(new ElasticSearchSinkOptions()).CreateLogger();
```

Could someone who is already using this let me know if the versions of both the nuget packages makes sense. I have downloaded all the latest packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a list of packages used in a similar POC

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Elasticsearch.Net" version="5.5.0" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="Microsoft.DotNet.InternalAbstractions" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration" version="2.0.0" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions" version="2.0.0" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder" version="2.0.0" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions" version="2.0.0" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" version="2.0.0" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" version="2.0.0" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions" version="2.0.0" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Abstractions" version="2.0.0" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Physical" version="2.0.0" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.FileSystemGlobbing" version="2.0.0" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging" version="2.0.0" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions" version="2.0.0" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console" version="2.0.0" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" version="2.0.0" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Options" version="2.0.0" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions" version="2.0.0" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives" version="2.0.0" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="10.0.1" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="Serilog" version="2.5.0" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="Serilog.Extensions.Logging" version="2.0.2" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="Serilog.Settings.Configuration" version="2.4.0" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="Serilog.Sinks.Elasticsearch" version="5.4.0" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="Serilog.Sinks.File" version="3.2.0" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="Serilog.Sinks.PeriodicBatching" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="Serilog.Sinks.RollingFile" version="3.3.0" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="System.Linq" version="4.1.0" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="System.Resources.ResourceManager" version="4.0.1" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="System.Runtime" version="4.1.0" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe" version="4.4.0" targetFramework="net462" />
</packages

Take a look at this article, it should help because it is focused exactly on this topic:

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1218350/Elasticsearch-Kibana-and-Docker-using-NET-Standard

Comment: Sorry for the quality of this answer, I used my mobile phone to write it.